# Wrong result for pandas timestamp - dateoffset

Tags: python, pandas

Strangely enough:

```
In[]:  import pandas as pd
       pd.Timestamp('2015-10-10') - pd.DateOffset(month=1)
Out[]: Timestamp('2015-01-10 00:00:00')
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS:

```
pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 2.7.10.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Linux
OS-release: 3.13.0-63-generic
machine: x86_64
processor: x86_64
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_US.UTF-8

pandas: 0.16.2
nose: 1.3.7
Cython: 0.23.3
numpy: 1.9.2
scipy: 0.16.0
statsmodels: 0.6.1
IPython: 4.0.0
sphinx: 1.3.1
patsy: 0.3.0
dateutil: 2.4.2
pytz: 2015.4
bottleneck: 1.0.0
tables: 3.2.0
numexpr: 2.4.3
matplotlib: 1.4.3
openpyxl: 1.8.5
xlrd: 0.9.3
xlwt: 1.0.0
xlsxwriter: 0.7.3
lxml: 3.4.4
bs4: 4.3.2
html5lib: None
httplib2: None
apiclient: None
sqlalchemy: 1.0.5
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
>>> pd.Timestamp('2015-10-10') - pd.DateOffset(month=9)
Timestamp('2015-09-10 00:00:00', tz=None)
```

This may be even better for you though:

```
>>> pd.Timestamp('2015-10-10') - pd.DateOffset(months=1)
Timestamp('2015-09-10 00:00:00', tz=None)
```

You're setting `month` but you want to set `months`. Minute difference.

Comment: aughhhhh +1 for setting me on the right track.  What I meant was `... - pd.DateOffset(months=1)`  (monthSSSSSSS, plural). Dang it.

Comment: I spent 1/2 hour debugging some arcane piece of code for one missing 's'.

Comment: Here, when working with ```pd.DateOffset``` using years of timestamp, it gives a lot of duplicated results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much @rofls for noting that `pd.DateOffset(month=X)` will SET the month to X.  What I wanted was simply to subtract one month.  This seems to be achieved with `... - pd.DateOffset(months=1)`.  ("months" plural, even though there is just one to remove).